# How to run external application which are downloaded , using python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess, project

I am making a game launcher project and I want to run the game when clicked on the play button, so, what should be the code in the function run_game? I know that we can use subprocess for internal application which comes with windows, but I want to run external applications like games.
please help..

```
def browse():
global name
global app_bro
global data
global f
global g
global list_of
app_bro = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='',filetype = [('Application', '*.exe')])
name = os.path.basename(app_bro)
moment=time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime())



f_name = 'C:/Users/vatsa/Desktop/Launcher/mygames/'+name+'.txt'

with open(f_name, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(name, f)



with open(f_name , 'rb') as f:
    list_of = pickle.load(f)
```

This is the browse function where the user can select the app they want to add into the launcher, once they select it, the game adds to My games section, now how can i exactly run the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the standard way would be to use subprocess:

```
import subprocess
win_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\<path_to_game>'
process = subprocess.Popen(win_cmd,
shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
```